# how to extract value of a variable defined in a function using inspect module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

I am trying to access a particular variable that is defined in a function in python module. I was able to get to the variable name(using inspect.getmembers()) function, I was able to extract all variables that are defined in the function of interest in the (co_varnames) attribute. How do I get the value assigned to the variable ? Here is the sample code:-

```
    File 1:- input.py

    class foo(self):
        def some_fun():
            some_var='abc'

    File 2:- sample.py

    imported_module = importlib.import_module(input) 
    all_varnames = inspect.getmembers(imported_module)
    -->> need value of all_varnames['some_var']
```

Comment: Your indentation is invalid, fix it. What exactly do you expect to achieve by extracting the values?

Comment: These variables hold information (as dict) related to the function that I need to eventually copy to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and suggestions. @Thomas Wagenaar.@skyking.

This is what I finally ended up doing that, I defined the variable like this inside the function:-

```
def testMethod(self):
    self.myvar = {'a':1,'b':2}
```

Then using a inspect module and getattr(), I could instantiate the class, call this testMethod(which failed with exception), but got to a point where the variable was initialized and then just read the variable. I dont know if the solution is "correct" way of doing things in python, but this little hack worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't in that context.

Local variables are only present during the execution of the function, that is between it has been called and returned. Your only possibility would be to do that in a function that the function calles (or if it's a generator during iteration).

Anyhow, if you do it in that way it will still be non-valid again after the function has returned.

Comment: Yes .I do get that locals() wont be available in the context. Is there a way to bring them on the stack without executing the imported module ? I was looking for inspect.stack() but that too always refers to the current context. So the only way out seems  to parse the source code using inspect.getsourcelines()

Comment: The only way to make them available while the function is not being executed is to globally (or statically) define them. Before even calling the function for them to be available you have to define an initialize them from global scope (you seem to have some confusion about `import` as it actually executes the module, that is runs the statements that are outside functions).

Comment: Yes I am fairly new to python, and thus may have a slight less understanding of what import does, but I do get now that it simply cant be done with the approach I was taking. Thanks a lot for your response.